# Copy cannot be resolved in split block

Tags: split, anylogic

When adding code (copy.setPosition(original.getPosition());) into a split block in the "on copy exit" portion, I get an error that says "copy cannot be resolved". What does this mean and how can you fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Felipe's solution is correct below. Just FYI: "copy" does not work as it is not a keyword in that field, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling

Comment: I'm finding it hard to find the link between your article and the. problem. I get that i should probably pay attention to the lightbulb, but I'm a lay-coder and that article isn't going into enough depth to decipher the message the light bulb is trying to tell me :p

Comment: "original" refers to ... the original agent arriving. "self" refers to the Split object. "agent" refers to the copied agent leaving. "indexCopy" refers to the index of the copied agent leaving (12th copy or however many you set).

Answer (score 0):

first, setPosition is not something you can use, and copy doesn't exist.

what you need to do is on the on exit copy action:

```
agent.jumpTo(original.getX(),original.getY());
```